# Install flameshot on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, backports

I found the program [*Flameshot*](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot) and tried to install it on *Debian Stretch*, but got the info:

```
E: Unable to locate package flameshot
```

On the site there is the info:

```
Package for Debian 9 ("Stretch") also available via stretch-backports.
```

Please tell me how to install it via `stretch-backports`?

I added `stretch-backports` string in `/etc/apt/source.list` next to each `stretch main contrib non-free` and got some error while `update` but some entries did not give the error:

```
s@lokal:~/Dropbox$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ftp.task.gda.pl/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:2 http://ftp.task.gda.pl/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://ftp.task.gda.pl/debian stretch Release                                                                  
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                           
Hit:5 http://nginx.org/packages/debian stretch InRelease                                       
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:8 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease
Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:11 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.task.gda.pl/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'stretch-backports/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'stretch-backports/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.task.gda.pl/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'stretch-backports/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
s@lokal:~/Dropbox$
```

The problem remains:

```
s@lokal:~/Dropbox$ sudo apt-get install flameshot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package flameshot
s@lokal:~/Dropbox$
```

How to install *Flameshot*?

Answer (score 3):

It's available in stretch-backports: [Package: flameshot](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/flameshot).

Add the backport repository.

Update and upgrade.

And then it should be installable.

Comment: how do i add the backport repository? then how do i update and upgrade?

Comment: @Kong maybe this site will help you: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-and-use-debian-backports

Comment: Excellent answer, step by step explanation is on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553049/185096

Answer (score 1):

To install *Flameshot* on *Debian 9 "Stretch"* add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

After saving the above file do update:

```
sudo apt update
```

After update install a package from backports using `apt` with the `-t` flag to specify the backports repository:

```
apt-get -t stretch-backports install flameshot
```

And then you have *Flameshot* installed.

You can run it from the command line by typing for example:

```
flameshot gui
```

Comment: ￼How to install flameshot screenshot software on Debian / Ubuntu / Arch / Fedora: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-flameshot-screenshot-software-on-linux

Comment: How To Install And Use Debian Backports: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-and-use-debian-backports